# PHP: Trouble with preg_match_all() return

Tags: php, format, preg-match-all, pcre

I'm writing this quick script to extract chatroom names from the source of a webpage. I'm grabbing the data with fopen() and fgets() and that all returns fine.

My regex is `/#[a-zA-z]+/`, which does seem to work. However I can not get `preg_match_all()` to return a concise list of data.

```
preg_match_all("/#[a-zA-z]+/", $contents, $foo, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($foo as $item) print $item;
```

Returns "ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray...".

```
print_r ($item);
```

Returns something along `( [0] => #channel1 ) Array ( [0] => #channe2 ) Array ( [0] => #channel3 )...`

I'm unsure how to get this formated properly, any quick help?

Comment: Depends on you want the output to be. How should it look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
$contents = '#channel1 #channel2 #channel3';

preg_match_all("/(#[a-zA-z0-9]+)/", $contents, $foo, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($foo);
echo '<hr />';

foreach($foo as $item)
   print $item[1].'<br />';
```

Comment: Still nothing. It just prepends each value of the the array with
 
`string[strlength of value]`

Comment: Show us the value of $contents and how you want the output to look

Answer (score 0):

Walked away and came back and it was pretty clear what was up. The desired values in the $foo array were wrapped in another array. I simply wrapped my `foreach()` statement with another `foreach()` statement thusly:

```
foreach($foo as $item) {
   foreach($item as $bar) {
     print $bar . "<br />";
   }
}
```

Worked without a hitch.